# Net::OpenSSH failing to connect with "ctr_dir is not secure" error

Tags: perl

I have a script that used to work suddenly stop working on me. I traced the problem back to a line that connects to a server with [`Net::OpenSSH`](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.74/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm). I set up a simple script to test `Net::OpenSSH`:

```
use Net::OpenSSH
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('myhost.com');
print $ssh->error;
```

This throws: `ctl_dir /home/me/.libnet-openssh-perl/ is not secure` error.

Module documentation says the following:

```
ctl_dir => $path
Directory where the SSH master control socket will be created.

This directory and its parents must be writable only by the current effective user or root, otherwise the connection will be aborted to avoid insecure operation.

By default ~/.libnet-openssh-perl is used.
```

The perms on the directory are 700. The dir is owned by me. The `/home` dir is owned by root. `/home/me` is owned by `me`. The script is owned and executed by `me`. Changing perms to 500 or 600 on `.libnet-openssh-perl` does not help.

I removed ~/.libnet-openssh-perl and let script create a new one for me. It did and set perms to 700. But the script still doesn't work. I've tried every other combination of perms and it still does not work.

The script stopped working a couple of months ago so I have no idea what server configuration could have changed that might have broken this.

Answer (score 1):

Setting /home/me directory to 755 fixed the issue.